# Is it possible to emulate a function using your own data type?

Tags: haskell, types, function-calls

Is it possible to emulate a function with your own data type with some GHC extension? What I want to do is e.g.

(imaginary syntax)

```
data MyFunc = MyFunc String (Int->Int)

instance (Int->Int) MyFunc where
    ($) (MyFunc _ f) i = f i

inc = MyFunc "increment" (1+)

test = inc 1
```

I.e. data that carries some meta-information with it and can be pattern matched, but which can still be called like a regular function. Now, I know that I could define my own infix operator like `$$` and call `inc $$ 1`, but being able to use the regular function call syntax would be very useful in embedded DSLs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it can be done to a limited extent.

But first we'll need

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
```

Let's define

```
data M a b = M { name :: Int -> String -> String, eval :: a -> b }
```

I'm adding more structure to your names so I can get nicer show support. ;)

Then lets define a class:

```
class Magic m where
    magic :: M a b -> m a b

instance Magic M where
    magic = id

instance Magic (->) where
    magic (M _ f) = f
```

Now, consider the type:

```
type MyFunc a b = forall m. Magic m => m a b
```

The result type of `magic` is either `(a -> b)` or a `M a b`.

So it can be used as a member of `MyFunc`. Now, this type is somewhat unsatisfying, because you can't make instances dispatch on it, but it does mean that

```
inc :: MyFunc Int Int
inc = magic (M (const (showString "inc")) (+1))

test :: Int
test = inc 1
```

works just fine.

We can even make a rather nice way to show them. Even though we can't use show on `MyFunc`, we can define it for `M`.

```
instance Show (M a b) where
    showsPrec d (M s _) = s d
```

Then we can make a function we can apply to `M a b` (and by extension any `MyFunc`) to get out an `M a b`.

```
m :: M a b -> M a b
m = id
```

and we can define a special combinator to show `MyFunc`s:

```
showM :: MyFunc a b -> String
showM f = show (m f)
```

Then we can play. We can define compositions of `MyFunc`s.

```
infixr 9 .#
(.#) :: MyFunc b c -> MyFunc a b -> MyFunc a c
f .# g = magic (M 
    (\d -> showParen (d > 9) $ showsPrec 10 (m f) . 
                               showString " . " . 
                               showsPrec 9 (m g)) 
    (f . g))

inc2 :: MyFunc Int Int
inc2 = inc .# inc

test2 :: Int
test2 = inc2 1

bar, baz :: String
bar = showM inc
baz = showM inc2
```

And because I gave enough structure to the names, we even get correct parenthesization for more complicated compositions, without needless parentheses.

```
*Main> showM $ inc2 .# inc
"(inc . inc) . inc"

*Main> showM $ inc .# inc2
"inc . inc . inc"
```

But remember, you won't be able to define any instances for `MyFunc`, since it can only be a `type`, and not a `newtype`. In order to define instances you'll have to define them on `M`, and then use `m` to convert to that type so that implicit dispatch has a type to grab onto.

Because of the rank 2 type, if you use these heavily in local contexts, you may also want to turn on `NoMonoLocalBinds` and/or `NoMonomorphismRestriction`.

Comment: This is kind of terrifying. I love it.

Answer (score 5):

No, the syntax `f e` cannot be overloaded.  The `f` has to have type `S -> T`.

But you can still do a lot with EDSLs if you do a deep embedding, i.e., you let your functions build syntax trees instead of computing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly overload function call syntax, no.

You *can* make your own custom arrow type --- see [Control.Arrow](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html). You can then invoke your "functions" using [arrow notation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/arrow-notation.html) (you will need to include `{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}` at the top of your source file). Whether this is good enough for you depends on the needs of your DSL.

Comment: Don't forget about applicatives!  They have an application operator too.