# Is it possible to define type with callable objects in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to haskell and not too comfortable with it's type system yet. And I wondering, if there is ability to define the type (datatype?), which instances can be called as functions?

Analogues are

```
__call__
```

method in Python or class method

```
operator()
```

in c++. (More examples are given in wikipedia for the word "Function object").

The example of application of such a construct is Polynom. The object is defined by list of its coefficients, i.e. I would like to have type like this:

```
data Num a => Polynom a = Polynom [a]
                          deriving (...)
```

Now of course I can define function

```
callPoly :: Num a => (Polynom a) -> a -> a
callPoly p x = ... -- implementation: extract coefficients of p,
                   -- construct polynomial and call it on x
```

(here I do not bother, to be able to call polynom with Int coefficients on Floats... it's just techincal details)

Now I can call it on my polinomial (in interactive prompt):

```
let myPoly = Polynomial [1 2 3]
let applicationResult = callPoly myPoly 3
```

But this way is not too fancy. Is is desirable to be able to call polynomial directly as

```
let applicationResult = myPoly 3
```

So the question is: It is possible to define such Polynomial type, which objects (instances) can be called (used as functions)? May be this pattern may be implemented in some other way, not involving 'data'? May be some playing with function types or smth. else?

Of course, this idea can be applied not only to polynomials. Actually, to any function, which must "has type" and has "some attached data" (in case of polynomial - it is coefficients).

Or if this is not possible, then is there some specific reason for this or it is just not supported?

P.S.: It seems to me, that direct approach (as described above) is impossible, because to be callable myPoly must be of type (Int -> Int). But type (Int -> Int) cannot have any data attached (i.g. polynomial coefficients). But I want to make sure, that I'm right.

Comment: What's wrong with `let myPoly = callPoly (Polynomial [1, 2, 3])`?

Comment: Why not just invent your own polynomial application 'sytax', e.g. `[] ||| x = 0 ; (c :cs) ||| x = c + x * (cs ||| x) `  Then in `ghci` you ask `[1,2,3,4,5] ||| 3` and get `547` as answer.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482970/is-it-possible-to-emulate-a-function-using-your-own-data-type

Comment: @shang Thanks. Latest link is exactly what i was looking for. Sorry, I did not find it myself.

Answer (score 8):

It's good that you're familiar with the C++ "function object" concept, because that's a good introduction to Haskell's idea of what you can do with plain old functions... Specifically, currying, partial application and passing functions as arguments to other functions.

In C++, your code would look something like:

```c++
class Polynomial {
  int coefficients[];
public:
  Polynomial(int coefficients[]) { /* ... */ }
  int operator() (int value) { /* ... */ }
};

int coefficients[] = {1, 2, 3};
Polynomial(coefficients)(4); // note the syntax here!
```

This is fundamentally expressing a single, pure function: a polynomial evaluator that takes a list of coefficients and a value.  It could just as easily have been expressed in C++ as:

```c++
int evaluatePolynomial(int coefficients[], int value);

int coefficients[] = {1, 2, 3};
evaluatePolynomial(coefficients, 4);
```

But this form isn't *curried* as the previous form is.  The nice thing about the curried form is you can say:

```c++
Polynomial p = Polynomial(coefficients);
p(4);
p(5);
p(6);
```

instead of:

```c++
evaluatePolynomial(coefficients, 4);
evaluatePolynomial(coefficients, 5);
evaluatePolynomial(coefficients, 6);
```

Okay.  So we're thinking of this "function object" thing as an object-oriented programming concept -- an object that masquerades as a function -- but let's forget objects now.  If you look at it in Haskell, it's just a function and doesn't require any user-defined datatypes to express nicely:

```hs
polynomial :: Num a => [a] -> a -> a
```

You can call it "normally" (as with `evaluatePolynomial()` above), applying it to both arguments at once:

```hs
polynomial [1, 2, 3] 4
```

but because Haskell functions are curried, you can partially apply (as with the `Polynomial` function object):

```hs
do
  let p = polynomial [1, 2, 3]
  print (p 4)
  print (p 5)
  print (p 6)
```

Easy peasy.  Now, if you want to do something closer to C++ where you've got a specific data type representing your `Polynomial` function object, you can do that...

```hs
newtype Polynomial a = P (a -> a)  -- function object
mkPolynomial :: Num a => [a] -> Polynomial a  -- constructor
```

... but that extra complexity doesn't really offer any benefit.  You immediately notice that there's nothing special about `Polynomial`, it just wraps a regular function, so you end up having to just unwrap it again like:

```hs
do
  let (P p) = mkPolynomial [1, 2, 3]
  print (p 4)
  print (p 5)
  print (p 6)
```

In short, the more you frame your thinking purely in terms of functions, rather than objects, the simpler and more idiomatic your Haskell code will end up being.

Comment: Thanks for this tutorial. The idea is nice. But I still think in OO style. With your solution I do not understand, how to define other operations (add, differentiate etc...) and those should be polimorphic. E.g. I can either have splines, which either should be callable and have addition and differentiation etc. I cannot understand, how to adopt your solution to this case. The problem is that in p we have lost information about coefficients (which in my understanding should be encapsulated into polynomial object).

Comment: Well, if you want, you can define `newtype Polynomial a = Num a => P { coefficients :: [a] }` and `evaluatePolynomial :: Num a => Polynomial a -> a -> a`.  This is essentially the same as your original definition.  But it's also the same as mine, with just a bit of extra type sugar.  You can still say `let p = evaluatePolynomial (P [1, 2, 3])` or whatever.

Comment: This still has the same issue (which I try to solve in this questions): the value, which has info about coefficients and value, which is function are distinct (they are bound to different variables). But I want, that those to be the same. In this case it is nicer (IMHO) to define `class Callable a ...` with infix operation like `(|||) :: (a Int) -> Int -> Int` and implement this operation for Polynomial. And then call it as `let y = myPoly ||| x` (this solution was proposed in other answers). Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Comment: The `Callable` class you propose already exists as [`Category`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Category.html).  There's also a handy data type that exists which models `Category` nicely: `(->)`.  Your infix `(|||)` operation is the same as my `polynomial` function above.  That is, I could have called it `(|||)` and thus been able to write `[1, 2, 3] ||| 4`.  Point is, the solutions are identical; I'm trying to help you get away from OO thinking which only complicates the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I may get my terminology wrong here, as I am no Haskell veteran myself.  However, from my understanding of Haskell:

As Haskell is not object-oriented, it does not have objects or instances (in the traditional sense, that is).  Instead of instances of a datatype, you have a values of the datatype.  That being said, since functions are data (values) just like integers and strings, you can have values that are callable in the sense that they can carry their own context (like an instance in OO world would).

If your goal is to have a value you pass around that carries the `PolyNom a`, you could simply *partially evaluate* your function `callPoly`, then think of that as your "Callable PolyNom".  Example:

```
myPoly = PolyNom [1, 2, 3]
callMyPoly = callPoly myPoly

-- or simply

callMyPoly = callPoly (PolyNom [1, 2, 3])
```

Now, the type of callMyPoly is:

```
callMyPoly :: Num a => a -> a
```

and you can call it like this:

```
callMyPoly 5
```

which is equivalent to:

```
callPoly myPoly 5
```

Comment: The type of `callMyPoly` is only polymorphic if the monomorphism doesn't apply. If you define `callMyPoly` as given, the MR applies (if not disabled per -XNoMonomorphismrestriction or pragma). To get the polymorphic type, 1) give a type signature 2) bind with an argument, `callMyPoly x = callPoly myPoly x` or 3) disable MR.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in Haskell you can't have callable objects as that would mess up type-inference a lot. You will have to give explicit names to your functions, just like in OO languages that don't support `__call__` and need explicit method names.

On the other hand, partial function application and closures make it very easy to obtain a polynomial-function from a polynomial-representation so the limitation is not that bad.

```
let polyF = callPoly myPoly in
(polyF 17) + (polyF 42)
```